# Redirect a URL in Sharepoint 2013 without creating a new page

Tags: redirect, sharepoint, http-status-code-404, sharepoint-2013

I've had to update a page's URL in Sharepoint 2013, and now all distributed links to the original URL lead to a 404 error:

**Original**

```
http://example.com/abc/Pages/default.aspx
```

**Current**

```
http://example.com/xyz/Pages/default.aspx
```

Is there any way to redirect `abc/Pages/default.aspx` to point to `zyx/Pages/default.aspx` from within Sharepoint?

Comment: Haha, I just noticed years after originally asking this question the sheer number of Views vs Answers - perhaps Microsoft should consider this a feature request.

Comment: They did! In SP2013, there is a redirect page layout.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a script part to the original page with this block of code to redirect users when they land on the page.

```
<script>
window.location="http://example.com/xyz/Pages/default.aspx"
</script>
```

It sounds like the default.aspx file has been removed in this original location as well, so you will need to re-add an empty page with the same filename first.

Comment: Thanks, but this seems very technically long-winded for a simple CMS redirect. So there's no way of achieving a redirect without adding code or creating dummy pages?

Comment: @Timmah If you're using on-premise you could use HTTP-Rewrite in IIS but in general, no, SharePoint doesn't provide any functionality for this out of the box.